React native absolute path import doesn't work with react-native but works with expo
I have a problem with absolute paths. When i start my app with npx expo run:android everything works correct. When I'm trying to run with npx react-native run-android i'm facing a problem.
Error: Unable to resolve module @helpers/i18n/i18n from {rest of path}\project\src\init\App.tsx: @helpers/i18n/i18n could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  2 | // See LICENSE.txt for license information.
  3 |
> 4 | import '@helpers/i18n/i18n';
    |         ^
  5 | import {PortalProvider} from '@gorhom/portal';
  6 | import {Navigation} from '@navigation/navigation';
  7 | import AppInitializer from '@providers/app-initializer';

It doesn't happen when I run with expo.
This problem occurs only when I try import whole file or function which is exported default.
Below my tsconfig.json
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*" : ["src/components/*"],
      "@screens/*" : ["src/screens/*"],
      "@store/*" : ["src/store/*"],
      "@utils/*" : ["src/utils/*"],
      "@navigation/*" : ["src/navigation/*"],
      "@hooks/*" : ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@helpers/*" : ["src/helpers/*"],
      "@core/*" : ["src/core/*"],
      "@constants/*" : ["src/constants/*"],
      "@config/*" : ["src/config/*"],
      "@common/*" : ["src/common/*"],
      "@api/*" : ["src/api/*"],
      "@actions/*" : ["src/actions/*"],
      "@providers/*" : ["src/providers/*"],
      "@types" : ["src/types/types.d.ts"],
      "@assets/*" : ["./assets/*"],
      "@common-types": ["src/types/common-types.d.ts"]

    }

I was even trying to add babel module resolver which was not required with expo absolute path config.
plugins: [
            ['module-resolver', {
                alias: {
                    '@components/*': ['./src/components*'],
                    '@screens/*': ['./src/screens'],
                    '@store/*': ['./src/store'],
                    '@utils/*': ['./src/utils'],
                    '@navigation/*': ['./src/navigation'],
                    '@hooks/*': ['./src/hooks'],
                    '@helpers': ['./src/helpers'],
                    '@core/*': ['./src/core'],
                    '@constants/*': ['./src/constants'],
                    '@config/*': ['./src/config'],
                    '@common/*': ['./src/common'],
                    '@api/*': ['./src/api'],
                    '@actions/*': ['./src/actions'],
                    '@providers/*': './src/providers',
                    '@types': ['./types/types.d.ts'],
                    '@assets/*': ['../assets'],
                    '@common-types': ['./src/types/common-types.d.ts'],
                },
            },
            ],

The problem is when i have a function whose is for example
const example = () => {

}

export default example;

so import looks like
import example from '@helpers/example'

and it doesnt work
but when I make this function as;
export const example = () => {

}

and import
import {example} from '@helpers/example'

it works and error is not thrown.
What steps should i take to fix this problem?
